# Recreating a CryptoJS Hmac using python

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography, hmac, cryptojs

The scenario is that I have a JS script that creates a HMAC for a user provided input and I want to compute the same HMAC for the same input using python. To make things clearer, consider the following JS and Python code snippets.

**Javascript**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/hmac-sha256.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/enc-base64.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var secretAccessKey = "bAvW5O18eSrxke4I7eFcrnrDJkN+wKQmx9aSHuMZQ0w=";
    var stringtoSign = "Test";

    // Generate HMAC SHA256 signature
    var secretAccessKeyBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(secretAccessKey);
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringtoSign, secretAccessKeyBase64);
    var signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
</script>
```

**Python**

```
stringToSign = "Test"
secretAccessKey = "bAvW5O18eSrxke4I7eFcrnrDJkN+wKQmx9aSHuMZQ0w="

secretAccessKeyBase64 = base64.b64decode(secretAccessKey).hex()
keyBytes = bytes(secretAccessKeyBase64, 'utf-8')
stringToSignBytes = bytes(stringToSign, 'utf-8')
signatureHash = hmac.new(keyBytes, stringToSignBytes, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature = base64.b64encode(signatureHash)
print(signature)
```

The Javascript code gives me **b+1wRzDODA85vyDZkXByPIKO5qmnjCRNF5gZFi33/Ic=**, while python gives me the value **b'SsZ4bcYe3op1nGU6bySzlSc9kgg9Kgp37qzF15s2zNc='**

Why is my python code generating a different HMAC for (seemingly) identical inputs that was provided to the JS script? Is there anyway to obtain the HMAC value outputted by the JS code using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a Base64 encoded value as secret in Javascript, whereas in Python you use the plain text secret.

```
<script>
    var secretAccessKeyBase64 = "secret";
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", secretAccessKeyBase64);
    var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
    document.write(hashInBase64);
</script>
```

This prints out the same value as the Python code:

```
qnR8UCqJggD55PohusaBNviGoOJ67HC6Btry4qXLVZc=
```

Edit:

base64 returns a byte-object there is no need to convert it to `hex()`:

```
stringToSign = "Test"
secretAccessKey = "bAvW5O18eSrxke4I7eFcrnrDJkN+wKQmx9aSHuMZQ0w="

secretAccessKeyBase64 = base64.b64decode(secretAccessKey)
keyBytes = secretAccessKeyBase64
stringToSignBytes = bytes(stringToSign, 'utf-8')

signatureHash = hmac.new(keyBytes, stringToSignBytes, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature = base64.b64encode(signatureHash)
print(signature)
```

Prints correctly:

```
b'b+1wRzDODA85vyDZkXByPIKO5qmnjCRNF5gZFi33/Ic='
```

Comment: Sorry i put the wrong code in earlier. Ive edited the question. Please have another look.

Comment: Edited my answer