# Different results trying to port SHA-1 digest from Python to browser JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography, sha1

**Main question**

I have the following short piece of legacy code that I am trying to port from Python (with just standard lib) to JavaScript - from the name of the methods I assume it creates a SHA-1 digest of the `abc` string

```py
import hashlib
import hmac

print(hmac.new(b"abc", None, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest())
```

I searched for how to do that in the browser in JS and found [the following code in the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest)

```js
var msgUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode('abc');
var hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-1', msgUint8);
var hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
var hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
console.log(hashHex)
```

the problem is, they yield two completely different results, and I have no idea why:

- `cc47e3c0aa0c2984454476d061108c0b110177ae` - Python
- `a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d` - JavaScript

I tried comparing the bytes of `b"abc"` with what `new TextEncoder().encode('abc')` returns and they are exactly the same: `0x61 0x62 0x63`, so the problem lies somewhere else and I have no idea where.

I need the JavaScript code to return what the Python code returns. Any ideas?

---

**Additionally**

My final goal is to actually port *this* code (note the `b"hello"` instead of `None`):

```
print(hmac.new(b"abc", b"hello", hashlib.sha1).hexdigest())
```

so if you have an idea on that one too - I would hugely appreciate it!

Comment: Might be helpful: [Recreating a CryptoJS Hmac using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317579/recreating-a-cryptojs-hmac-using-python/54317786#54317786)

Comment: Do you need a specific library (because your example uses WebCrypto) or is it irrelevant which JavaScript library is used?

Comment: @Topaco ideally it would be something that works on Firefox and Chrome without external dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python code calculates a SHA1 based HMAC. The JavaScript code on the other hand computes a SHA-1 hash. An [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) needs a key in addition to the data, while a [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) works without a key.

The first Python code uses the key `abc` and an *empty* message. The posted result for the HMAC is hex encoded:

```
cc47e3c0aa0c2984454476d061108c0b110177ae
```

The second Python code uses the same key and the message `hello`. The result for the HMAC is hex encoded:

```
d373670db3c99ebfa96060e993c340ccf6dd079e
```

The Java code determines the SHA-1 hash for `abc`. The result is

```
a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d
```

So all results are correct, but are generated with different input data or algorithms.

---

The calculation of the HMAC can be implemented with the *browser native* [WebCrypto-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) as follows:

```js
(async () => {
    var hmac = await calcHMac('abc', 'hello');
    console.log('HMAC: ', buf2hex(hmac)); 
    var hmac = await calcHMac('abc', '');
    console.log('HMAC: ', buf2hex(hmac)); 
})();
    
async function calcHMac(rawkey, data) {
    var key = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', utf8Encode(rawkey), {name: 'HMAC', hash: 'SHA-1'},true, ['sign']);        
    var hmac = await window.crypto.subtle.sign('HMAC', key, utf8Encode(data));
    return hmac;
}
    
function utf8Encode(str){
    return new TextEncoder().encode(str);
}
    
function buf2hex(buffer) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer), x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join(''); // from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031979/9014097 
}
```

and provides the same result as the two Python codes.

A remark to SHA-1: Although HMAC/SHA-1 is considered to be secure (contrary to SHA-1), there are arguments to switch to SHA-256, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15382).

---

The WebCrypto API is a bit cumbersome. A functionally identical implementation with [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#hmac), the library mentioned in the comment by Maurice Meyer, is simpler and looks like this:

```js
var hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1('hello', 'abc');
console.log('HMAC: ', hmac.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));

var hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1('', 'abc');
console.log('HMAC: ', hmac.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

but requires CryptoJS as external dependency.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That explains everything I wanted to know :) Have a great day.